# Magit - remove confirmation when popping stash

Tags: magit

Is there a way to remove a confirmation when popping a stash? [Documentation](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Action-Confirmation.html) say nothing about popping the stash. It says however that when dropping more than one stash, it has the confirmation by default.

However, I'm popping only one stash and I still get the confirmation, even after adding `(add-to-list 'magit-no-confirm 'drop-stashes)` to the config. Has someone made that work?

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the user option `magit-dwim-selection`, it is documented in [`(info "(magit) Completion and Confirmation")`](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Completion-and-Confirmation.html). For example,

```
(cl-nsubstitute '(magit-stash-pop nil t)
                '(magit-stash-pop nil ask)
                magit-dwim-selection
                :test #'equal)
```